# Retrieve latest post in each category - Forum

Tags: php, sql, forum

I'm building a forum, and I have ran into a few problems.

The basic database structure looks like this:

```
users
| user_id | username

categories
| category_id | category_name |

forum_posts
| post_id | ref_post_id (FK) | ref_category_id (FK) | ref_user_id (FK) | post_date |
```

If ref_post_id is 0 that means it's the main post of the thread that have a title. For answers to a thread ref_post_id equals the main post's post_id. I hope you understand.

How would I get the latest post in each category? Including the posts thread title, and the username from user table. Should I change my table structure and add a "latest_post_id" field to categories table or something?

Very greatful for your help. I know there are similar questions, but I'm also wondering about whether I should store latest_post_id and all that in categories table or have a huge query for retrieving everything on each page load.

**EDIT 2: HERE IS MY CURRENT QUERY:**

```
SELECT category_id, name, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE ref_category_id = category_id AND ref_post_id = 0) count_threads
(
SELECT title, ref_user_id, username FROM forum_posts
LEFT JOIN users ON user_id =     ref_user_id
WHERE latest_post_id = (SELECT MAX(latest_post_id) FROM forum_posts WHERE    ref_category_id = category_id LIMIT 1)
)
FROM forum_categories
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If this is going to be shown on every page load of the forum list, it probably makes sense to hold a cached `most_recent_post_id` or something similar in the forum table. Update that on a new post creation/edit/whatever logic you choose. Then, showing the most recent post is as easy as a `JOIN` as opposed to multiple queries or a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a creation date you need to get the one with the MAX date, if you don't you can use the MAX(post_id), but if you let user EDIT their post and you want to get the latest one created OR edited you should add a modification date to the database.

to get the latest post:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_posts p 
INNER JOIN users u ON p.ref_user_id=u.user_id
WHERE `post_id`=(SELECT max(`post_id`) FROM forum_posts WHERE ref_category_id=$value);
```

If you are using a date, just use that field instead of `post_id`

Comment: How would I also get the username? And title? I updated my question with my current query which does not retrieve latest post.

Comment: my query will retrieve everything in the forum_posts table, if you want to use the FK to get the normal values you have to use JOIN. I'll update my example

Comment: with that `JOIN` you will get the info of the user as well, hope that helps

Comment: Problem is that I can only get one field on my subquery. Please look at my new updated questionen where I select title and other things in a subquery. That does not work since I can only get one field that way. Hope you understand.